# MySQLのSQLで重複をのぞいた数をカウントしたい

Tags: mysql

### 質問

後述のサンプルデータでそれぞれのuser_idのfoodのユニーク数を知りたいのですが、どのようなSQLにすればよいでしょうか。

例えば下記の場合、
user_id=1は3 (apple, banana,melon)
user_id=2は1 (apple)
というような結果を得たいと思っています。

どのようなSQLにすればよいでしょうか。

何かしらの言語で取得して、それを再度集計ということは行いたくなく、できるだけSQLだけで完結させたいです。よろしくおねがいします。

### テーブル

users

### レコード

id,user_id,food
1,1,apple
2,1,apple
3,1,banana
4,1,melon
5,1,melon
6,2,apple
7,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT`で重複を取り除けるので、取り除いたフィールドを`count`すればいいかと思います。

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT `food` ) FROM sample WHERE `user_id`=1;
```

ユーザごとに纏めるのであれば、`GROUP BY`すると良いと思います。

```
SELECT `user_id`, count( DISTINCT `food` ) FROM sample GROUP BY `user_id`;
```

※サンプルデータと実行結果です。
[image: sample]